# magento admin url redirect to home page automatically

Tags: magento, redirect

I faced a strang problem: When I want to login admin page, but it automatically redirect to home page.

our shop url is www.bestinnature.ca, the admin page is www.bestinnature.ca/index.php/admin.

could some give me some advice?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to make changes in the core_config_data table in your database.

Regards
Vikk

Comment: make changes in web unsecure & secure URLs

Comment: I checked in database:                                     web/unsecure/base_url  http://bestinnature.ca/
web/secure/base_url  https://bestinnature.ca/              They are okay. And I did not add ssl for admin page.

Comment: I also find that I can login the admin url by IE, but not for FF and Chrome. I deleted all history in FF, but still useless.

Comment: It works fine when I remove it to localhost. So It is not because of magento itself, but the server. Then what's the reason????

Comment: Why the admin url redirect to home page? Who could give some advice? Is this the problem no one can solve?

Comment: what configuration is to be used?

Comment: Downvoted due to lack of an actual answer. Please provide configuration changes you have made.

Answer (score 0):

Play with site.com/magento/custom_admin_name to site.com/magento/index.php/custom_admin_name

Comment: this happened to me today, use your fix as a long shot, it works.  wondering why it worked?